# How can i remove /index in URL in routing in cakePHP?

Tags: cakephp

I want to remove /index in URL.

```
Router::connect('/Home/:index', array('controller' => 'Homes'));
```

and :

```
Router::connect('/Home/', array('controller' => 'Homes','action'=>'index'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need do something like`Router::connect('/', array('controller'=>'Homes', 'action'=>'index'));` without '/Home/:index'